# How to Plot the resultant of NMinimize?

Tags: plotting

I am using NMinimize to find the Global minimum of my energy, and I want to plot the list of variables (x1,x2,...) versus ne (number of electrons). How do I make a ListPlot for example?

Here is my code:

```
 \[ScriptL]0 = 8;
 ne = 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2;
 vars = Array[Symbol["x$" <> ToString[#]] &, ne]
 cons = Apply[And, Thread[0 <= vars <= \[Pi]/2]]

 mtablep = Join[{0}, Flatten[Table[{i, -i}, {i, 1, \[ScriptL]0}]]]

 M[\[ScriptL]_, p1_, p2_, pp1_, pp2_] := 
 If[mtablep[[p1]] + mtablep[[p2]] == mtablep[[pp1]] + mtablep[[pp2]], 
 Sum[(2 \[ScriptL] + 1)^2 (2 \[ScriptL]temp + 1)/(4 \[Pi] )
 Sum[If[mtablep[[p1]] + mtablep[[p2]] == mval && 
   mtablep[[pp1]] + mtablep[[pp2]] == mval, 
  ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL], mtablep[[p1]]}, {\[ScriptL], 
     mtablep[[
      p2]]}, {\[ScriptL]temp, -mval}] ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL], 
     mtablep[[pp1]]}, {\[ScriptL], 
     mtablep[[
      pp2]]}, {\[ScriptL]temp, -mval}] ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL], 
     0}, {\[ScriptL], 0}, {\[ScriptL]temp, 0}]^2, 
    0], {mval, -\[ScriptL]temp, \[ScriptL]temp}], {\[ScriptL]temp, 
    0, 2 \[ScriptL]}], 0]

   ene[ang_?ListQ] := 
   Sum[(Cos[ang[[p1]]] Sin[ang[[pp1 + 1]]] - 
   Sin[ang[[p1 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[pp1]]] + 
   If[p1 == pp1, Sin[ang[[p1 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[p1]]], 
   0]) (Cos[ang[[p2]]] Sin[ang[[pp2 + 1]]] - 
   Sin[ang[[p2 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[pp2]]] + 
   If[p2 == pp2, Sin[ang[[p2 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[p2]]], 
   0]) M[\[ScriptL]0, p1, p2, pp1, pp2], {p1, 1, 
   2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1}, {p2, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1}, {pp1, 1, 
   p1}, {pp2, 1, p2}] // N

   NMinimize[{ene[vars], cons}, vars, 
    Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Replacing `Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"` by `Method -> "RandomSearch"`, I obtain `{1728.03, {-2.24514, {x$1 -> 1.5708, x$2 -> 0.562764, x$3 -> 0., 
   x$4 -> 0., x$5 -> 1.5708, x$6 -> 0.8755, x$7 -> 0., x$8 -> 0., 
   x$9 -> 1.5708, x$10 -> 0.893709, x$11 -> 0., x$12 -> 0., 
   x$13 -> 1.5708, x$14 -> 0.881111, x$15 -> 0., x$16 -> 0., 
   x$17 -> 1.5708, x$18 -> 1.5708}}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[ℓ0_Integer?NonNegative] := f[ℓ0] =
  Module[
   {ne = 2 ℓ0 + 2, vars, cons, mtablep, M, ene},
   vars = Array[Symbol["x$" <> ToString[#]] &, ne];
   cons = Apply[And, Thread[0 <= vars <= π/2]];
   mtablep = Riffle[Range[0, -ℓ0, -1], Range[ℓ0]];
   M[ℓ_, p1_, p2_, pp1_, pp2_] := 
    If[mtablep[[p1]] + mtablep[[p2]] == 
      mtablep[[pp1]] + mtablep[[pp2]],
     Sum[(2 ℓ + 1)^2 (2 ℓtemp + 1)/(4 π) 
       Sum[
        If[mtablep[[p1]] + mtablep[[p2]] == mval && 
          mtablep[[pp1]] + mtablep[[pp2]] == mval,
         ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, mtablep[[p1]]}, {ℓ, 
            mtablep[[p2]]}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] *
          ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, mtablep[[pp1]]}, {ℓ, 
            mtablep[[pp2]]}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] *
          ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ, 0}, {ℓ, 
             0}, {ℓtemp, 0}]^2, 0],
        {mval, -ℓtemp, ℓtemp}],
      {ℓtemp, 0, 2 ℓ}], 0];
   ene[ang_?VectorQ] :=
    Sum[(Cos[ang[[p1]]] Sin[ang[[pp1 + 1]]] - 
        Sin[ang[[p1 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[pp1]]] +
        If[p1 == pp1, Sin[ang[[p1 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[p1]]], 
         0]) (Cos[ang[[p2]]] Sin[ang[[pp2 + 1]]] - 
        Sin[ang[[p2 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[pp2]]] +
        If[p2 == pp2, Sin[ang[[p2 + 1]]] Cos[ang[[p2]]], 
         0]) M[ℓ0, p1, p2, pp1, pp2],
     {p1, 1, 2 ℓ0 + 1}, {p2, 1, 2 ℓ0 + 1}, {pp1, 1, 
      p1}, {pp2, 1, p2}];
   {ne, #} & /@ 
    NArgMin[{ene[vars], cons}, vars, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]]
```

Generate plot data

```
data = f /@ Range[0, 10];
```

Plotting

```
ListPlot[data,
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style[Subscript[n, e], 14, Bold], None}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Method->"RandomSearch"` produces a better value of the objective function.

Comment: Thanks a lot user64494

Comment: @Bob Hanlon , Thak you Bob, I have a question what does this " {ne, #}" before the function maping symbol, why do we need ne in there?

Comment: `ListPlot[{3, 1, 5, 4, 2}]` would assume that the data points are `{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}}`. Since you want the data points associated with the current value of `ne`, you need to specify the value of `ne` as the x coordinate for the points. The mapping  converts the list of variable values into a list of points with the value of `ne` as the x coordinate.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon How do I get to know the value of the minimum  energy associated to the the list that minimizes the energy? I guess in your version of code the number of electrons are changing between 0,10; but in my version I just have ten electrons , the list I have from 1 to ten is the angles associated to the spin of each electron and I want to find the angle structure or list for which my energy is minimum. Is that the same in your version? I am a little bit confused about if they are doing the same thing or not

Comment: "plot the list of variables (x1, x2, ...) versus ne", so I did. To get value of energy use `NMinimize` to get both energy as well as values for the variables. As shown in the `ListPlot` the `ne` runs from 2 to 22, the input to `f` is `\[ScriptL]0`which is what is varying from 0 to 10. You say you have just 10 electrons but the code you provided used `\[ScriptL]0 = 8; ne = 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2`, i.e., 18 electrons. And, you cannot plot versus number of electrons if the number is fixed. I have no idea what your code is doing, I merely tried to "plot the list of variables (x1, x2, ...) versus ne".

Comment: @Bob Hanlon  My bad, I didn't explain my question well, but I got my answer after playing with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have another question Bob. I want to force the fisrt and last element of varsto be zero and Pi/2 respectively. How do I do that without getting the error that the first element is not a variable?

Comment: Add additional constraints, i.e., `cons = Apply[And, Thread[0 <= vars <= Pi/2]] && First[vars] == 0 && Last[vars] == Pi/2;`